# created workflow (associated workflow) isn't showed in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a basic custom list, in SPD, I've clicked on Workflows/New.., input a name, set condition/action, Save and Publish.

But when I get back to Lists and Libraries/my_list I don't see workflows showed on Workflows panel. 
What's wrong with my site?

[image]

**Update:** when I open the list in browser, those workflows are shown but they don't work at all. 
[image]
@M.Qassas : I've just started learning Sharepoint workflow, so it's quite simple, I have a list with Title (default), Total (Number), Remain (Number). 
My workflow tend to auto trigger everytime an item created, set Remain = Total. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you see it under List settings >> Workflow Settings ?

Comment: When I open list in browser, it's showed, but the workflow doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please, share your workflow steps to check Why it not works?

Comment: @M.Qassas I've update question to be more detail on my workflow, please have a look!

Comment: Can you confirm Workflow Settings of the Workflow(WF) under Workflow tab in SPD are set to run WF on item added and updated?